# Multi line of $wpdb->query just run 1 time and end the loop right after

Tags: wp-query, customization, bug

```
    <?php 
foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) {

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post,true);
    //var_dump($post);

    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET VenueLongitude = '$VenueLongitude' WHERE ID=$post_id"));
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET VenueLatitude = '$VenueLatitude'  WHERE ID=$post_id"));
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET  Tag = '$Tag' WHERE ID=$post_id"));
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET IsDeleted  = '$IsDeleted' WHERE ID=$post_id"));
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET AdminID = '$AdminID' WHERE ID=$post_id"));
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET CreatedAt = '$CreatedAt' WHERE ID=$post_id"));
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET VenueStreet = '$VenueStreet' WHERE ID=$post_id"));
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET VenueNumber = '$VenueNumber' WHERE ID=$post_id"));
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET VenueDistrict = '$VenueDistrict' WHERE ID=$post_id"));
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET VenueCity = '$VenueCity'  WHERE ID=$post_id"));
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET VenueWard = '$VenueWard' WHERE ID=$post_id"));
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET PriceAverage = '$PriceAverage' WHERE ID=$post_id"));
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_posts SET Near = '$Near' WHERE ID=$post_id"));

    }
    ?>
```

I attached the code in which I run mutli wpdb->query in a foreach loop. But after the loop run 1 time it stopped immediately, it just runs only 1 time. It is ok if I just run 1 wpdb->query in the loop. How can I fix this problem? Anybody can help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your code has serious security issues - check the [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) for the proper way of using `wpdb::prepare()`. Secondly, you could use [`wpdb::update()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/) instead of `$wpdb->query()`. And third, none of the fields you're *updating* (e.g. `VenueLongitude`) exists in the standard WordPress posts [table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts).

Comment: If you want to update custom fields of a post, you can use [`update_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/).